# carousel play/pause buttons not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have written the following code. The buttons work when they hovered over but don't work when clicked
This is the code of buttons in the carousel.

```
 <div class="btn-group" id="carouselbutton">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-pause">
                <span class="fa fa-pause"></span>
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-play">
                <span class="fa fa-play"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
```

The following is the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mycarousel").carousel({ interval: 1000 });
        $("#carousel-pause").click(function () {
          $("#mycarsousel").carousel("pause");
        });
        $("#carousel-play").click(function () {
          $("#mycarousel").carousel("cycle");
        });
      });
```

Comment: Here is the link to entire required code https://codepen.io/Swasthik0304/pen/pojWmgm

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. And most likely the problem is somewhere else ... I guess.
I made you a working code with yours settings.

I hope I've been helpful.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <style>
        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
        }
      </style>

    </head>
    <body>



        <div class="container">

            <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="item1 active"></li>
                <li class="item2"></li>
                <li class="item3"></li>
                <li class="item4"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="btn-group" id="carouselbutton">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-pause">
              <span class="fa fa-pause">PAUSE</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-play">
              <span class="fa fa-play">PLAY</span>
            </button>
          </div>


          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#mycarousel").carousel({interval: 1000});

                // Click on the button to start sliding 
                $("#carousel-play").click(function(){
                    $("#mycarousel").carousel("cycle");
                });

                // Click on the button to stop sliding 
                $("#carousel-pause").click(function(){
                    $("#mycarousel").carousel("pause");
                });

            });
          </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey, your code works fine. I find it similar to mine but mine don't work. Is there a possibility that there is an issue with bootstrap/jquery/popper.

Comment: Most likely different versions of bootstrap or jquery?